# Is there any limitations on using OpenStreetMap with Leaflet or OpenLayers in request count?

Tags: leaflet, openlayers, openstreetmap, geolocation, limitations

I have a project that needs an online map to determine customer current location and store location, so calculate the distance between them and the price of shipping. If this app can be able to navigate shipping vehicle from store to customer location is better. I used to get GoogleMaps API first but it has limitations and must be paid. So I want to change GoogleMaps location service in my project with open source ones and I decided to use Leaflet or OpenLayers those using OpenStreetMap. Now I don't know if there is exist any limitation same the GoogleMaps in request numbers. May I ban for extra requests or something?

Comment: OpenStreetMap is a vector database, not a tile provider. Do read https://switch2osm.org/using-tiles/ and https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/ and https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/tiles/

Comment: In what way are Leaflet or OpenLayers connected with your question since they don't have any built in location service?

Comment: @TomazicM Leaflet and OpenLayers have implementations based on OpenStreetMap data and maps. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, there are many implementations of maps with Leaflet and OpenLayers using OpenStreet maps from various providers, but in your question you mentioned location service.

Comment: @IvanSanchez I heard about that. I just want to use location service like GoogleMap API for our users to determine their locations and calculate distance from other locations. GoogleMap service needs a subscription and paying money. Free services like Leaflet not. But I don't know if they have some limitations in API call or request numbers or some other stuff!

Comment: @TomazicM Isn't location service one of the benefit of these services?

Comment: You gotta be more specific in your question, because I (we?) am not sure if you want basemap tiles, geolocation, geocoding, reverse geocoding, route finding, or something else.

Comment: Neither Leaflet or OpenLayers offer any map services, they are just libraries for creating online maps, using standard map services from any provider that offers them. On the other hand for example Mapbox provides both map services and development libraries, but it's of course payable.

Comment: @IvanSanchez I'm new in developing apps based on online maps. You right. I'll update my question and try to clarify what I need. Thanks so much.

Comment: @TomazicM Thanks. My question updated. Can you please check it again and write extra advise if any?

Comment: You will need to use a third party directions API. There are several alternatives where an API key has a free monthly limit (varies with the service you choose) and beyond the limit you will need a paid account. These are some of the global services
 https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/rest-services/routes/
 https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/8.16.0/api-reference-swagger.html
 https://docs.mapbox.com/api/navigation/directions/
 https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/directions-api/
 https://openrouteservice.org/dev/#/api-docs/directions

Comment: @Mike This is Exactly what I need to know. Thanks so much.